# Can you iterate the values of an array that is stored as an item in a scripting.dictionary object?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, vbscript

I would like to get the returned values from this given code.

```
  Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "What is your favorite word? "
        wordReply = wscript.stdin.readline   
  wscript.stdout.writeline "Enter a number: "
        num1 = cint(wscript.stdin.readline)
  wscript.stdout.writeline "Enter a number: "
        num2 = cint(wscript.stdin.readline)
  wscript.stdout.writeline "Enter a number: "
        num3 = cint(wscript.stdin.readline)
  wscript.stdout.writeline "Enter a number: "
        num4 = cint(wscript.stdin.readline)
  wscript.stdout.writeline "Enter a number: "
            num5 = cint(wscript.stdin.readline)
    newWord = wordReply
 set wordReply = new CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    wordReply.Add newWord, Array(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)
```

I want to return or display using Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine the values prompted that are now inside an array keyed under the newWord item of wordReply. Can this be done successfully? I have seen numerous examples of how to iterate through a scripting dictionary object but never through an array that is inside of a value of a scripting object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a dictionary `d` contains an array (1, 2, 3) under/for a key ("aWord"), then `d("aWord")` gives you **a copy** of that array, that can be treated as every array in VBScript. Evidence:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d("aWord") = Array(1, 2, 3)
>> WScript.Stdout.WriteLine Join(d("aWord"), "-")
>>
1-2-3
>>
```

If you insist on iterating:

```
>> For i = 0 To UBound(d("aWord"))
>>     WScript.Echo d("aWord")(i)
>> Next
>>
1
2
3
```